# Jacobian matrix: Inequality between number of rows and columns

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, control-theory, jacobian

To find the Jacobian matrices, we have to take partial derivatives of the differential equations according to state variables. For example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant),

[image]

In my system, i have 8 differential equations, but number of state variables is 9. So, Jacobian is not square matrix. As a result, i cannot use this matrix in state space modelling.

How can i fix my problem? Should i define new differential equation or change the state variables?

Thanks,

Comment: There are no differential equations in your post. Can you explain  this point?

Comment: I want to take suggestions for this kind of problems. So, i haven't added them.

Comment: Is your system subjected to any constraints, which would indirectly define the dynamics of the 9th state?

Comment: There is no constraints now, but next steps there will be changes. I'm not sure. In my opinion, i have to define new differential equation like x1_dot=x2. By the increasing of the differential equations, A matrix of Jacobian can be square and number of S.V. and D.E. can be same. Finally, Jacobian A will have a row which contains a lot of "0".

Comment: @voo What does "but next steps there will be changes" mean? You should really add equations to your question that clarify what you actually mean. At the moment your question is very unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the 9th variable is not a state, but an external input, e.g., the control signal. Consider the example
$$\begin{aligned}\dot{x}_1 &= f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3),\\ \dot{x}_2 &= f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3).\end{aligned}$$
Then your linearization (I assume here that you linearize around the origin that is the equilibrium) is
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f_1 & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}f_1 \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f_2 & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}f_2\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}f_1 \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}f_2 \end{bmatrix} x_3
\end{aligned}
$$
I.e., the Jacobian is $2\times 3$, but the linearization state matrix is only $2 \times 2$ as it includes only those state for which you have the differential equations.